# two-dimensional strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, c-strings

I just started learning C a few weeks ago, by following a book about C. Each chapter has some exercises at the end, and there's an exercise I can't   figure out why my code doesn't work. The assignment was to get from the user a few strings, that will enter into a two-dimensional array. then, to print each string backwards.

For example,

The user will enter the words: `sleep`, `hello`, `great`,

and the output will be: `peels`, `olleh`, `taerg`.

It has to be a two-dimensional array (that's what the chapter is about).

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char string[5][6]; 
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("please enter a string:\n");
        scanf("%s", &string[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(j=6; j<=0; j--)
        {
            printf("%c", string[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        j=6;

    }

return 0;

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is your code not working - what output are you getting?

Comment: 1. It should be `scanf("%s", string[i]);` 2. It should be `for(j = 5; j >= 0; j--)` 3. No need to write `j = 6` again!

Comment: @kiner_shah `"5s"` typo as `"%5s"` (and `j=5` --> `j=last_char_index`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, corrected the typo and yes, it should be `j = last_char_index`!

Comment: @kiner_shah Why did you throw out **5**?

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. I mean `"5s"` --> `"%s"`, not `"%5s"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I got it now! Yes, it should be `%5s`!

Comment: There are no "2 dimensional strings". Strings are always 1D.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` need a `char *` you send a `char (*)[6]`.

`scanf("%s", &string[i]);` => `scanf("%5s", string[i]);`

Your `for` loop with `j` is wrong you print the nul terminate bytes. You should use a `while` loop in this case is more idiomatic in C.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    j = 5;
    while (j-- > 0) {
        printf("%c", string[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you code crashes. You are working only with strings that have five characters. Then you are printing out seven characters (indices 6,5,4,3,2,1,0). That is two too many. The first one (when starting with index six) causes read from outside of the array, which leads to undefined behavior. Then, when you are printing our character by character, you should not print out the end zero that is added to the string by scanf. It is not visible character. In this exercise you could replace it with space for example.

Also make sure you do not add any strings longer than five characters. That will also cause undefined behavior, very likely a crash. You can avoid that by making scanf to only read five character strings at most by replacing %s with %5s. Even then you have the problem or printing out garbage if the input string is less than five characters, so you should not set j to the length of the array but to the length of the string (minus one).

```
j=strlen(string)-1;
```

There may be also other issues, but fix those first and see what happens.

Comment: That's not really an answer, and nothing you pointed out would cause the program to crash.(Unless the input's incorrect)

Comment: True, reading outside of array boundary does not cause a crash (most of the time), only adding strings longer than 5 chars would make it crash.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily cause a crash just invoke undefined behaviour, plus there's no suggestion for how to ensure that doesn't happen and it's also doubtful that the op is giving input over 5 characters long.

Comment: @George: Accessing an array out of bounds (`string[i][6]`) provokes undefined behaviour and therefore might very well crash the program.

Comment: @George I added some instructions on how to avoid undefined behavior (likely crashes) and printing out garbage. Is it better now? :) Since Jessica is learning the language, I see no purpose on giving ready answers but rather pointing out the problems.